# Standart AnnotationView with Multiline in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to show my description of Annotation with several lines of text (such as phone, description, address), I found the solution [here](http://www.zen-sign.com/finding-business-listings-and-displaying-with-mapkit-part-3/). I must create my own child MKAnnotationView class and override method initWithAnnotation, where I'm able to draw background rectangle and all my labels with all settings I need. But I want to have standard background rectangle, it's rather pretty. Thanks for your help.